# Responsive Design with Foundation 6

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

First post using Stackflow, and super excited to be starting off on my web development career, I am using Foundation 6 to build out my first website and was hoping someone could point out some key aspects of my code that would allow it to become more responsive.. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to all of this!

Thanks!

```css
/* Left Header Block */

.header-left-block {
  background-image: url('../img/abstract_header_left.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}


.brand-title {
  font-size: 75px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 260px;
  font-family: poppins-Extralight;
}

/* Right Header Block */


.header-right-block {
  background-color: #FCDA02;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -2;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;

}

.header-right-content {

}

.slash {
  font-size: 125px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 400px 0px;
}

.sub-header {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: poppins-bold;
}

.search-text {
  font-family: poppins-regular;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px 10px;

}

.top-btns {
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px 30px;
}
/* Section Two */

.section-two {
  background-color:;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.section-two:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  background: #00ACC2;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin:;
  transform: skewY(-30deg);
  margin-top: -8px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.section-two-container {
  padding-bottom: 400px;
  align-content: flex-start;
}


.number {
    font-size: 20vw;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: poppins-mediumitalic;
}

.item-text {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 2vh;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2px;

}

.sub-header-one {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 5vh;
  font-family: poppins-bold;
  text-align: left;
}

.squiggel {
  z-index: 1;
}
/* Section Three */

.section-three {
  background-color:;
  height: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.section-three:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  background: #83C200;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: skewY(30deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.section-three-content {
  margin-top: -1500px;
}

.iphone {
  padding-left: 100px;
}

/* Section Four */

.section-four {
  background-color:#111;
  height: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 50px;
  margin-top: -800px;
}


  /* Menu */



  /* Media Queries */

  @media only screen and (max-width: 630px) {

.section-two-container {
  margin-top: -200px;

}

.section-three-content {
  margin-top: -100px;
}

.section-four {
  margin-top: -225px;
}

.sub-header-one {
  font-size: 4vh;
}

.number {

}

}


  /* Font */

@poppins-bold {
    font-family: poppins-bold;
    src: url(../fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf);
}

@poppins-regular {
    font-family: poppins-regular;
    src: url(../fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf);
}

@poppins-Extralight {
    font-family: poppins-extralight;
    src: url(../fonts/Poppins-ExtraLight.ttf);
}

@poppins-MediumItalic {
    font-family: poppins-mediumitalic;
    src: url(../fonts/Poppins-MediumItalic.ttf);
}

/* Mouse Scroll */

p {
  margin-left: -55px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes ani-mouse {
 0% {
 opacity: 1;
 top: 29%;
 }
 15% {
 opacity: 1;
 top: 50%;
 }
 50% {
 opacity: 0;
 top: 50%;
 }
 100% {
 opacity: 0;
 top: 29%;
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes ani-mouse {
 0% {
 opacity: 1;
 top: 29%;
 }
 15% {
 opacity: 1;
 top: 50%;
 }
 50% {
 opacity: 0;
 top: 50%;
 }
 100% {
 opacity: 0;
 top: 29%;
 }
}
@keyframes ani-mouse {
 0% {
 opacity: 1;
 top: 29%;
 }
 15% {
 opacity: 1;
 top: 50%;
 }
 50% {
 opacity: 0;
 top: 50%;
 }
 100% {
 opacity: 0;
 top: 29%;
 }
}
 .scroll-btn {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.scroll-btn > * {
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 18px;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #7f8c8d;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: "proxima-nova", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.scroll-btn > *:hover,
.scroll-btn > *:focus,
.scroll-btn > *.active {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.scroll-btn > *:hover,
.scroll-btn > *:focus,
.scroll-btn > *:active,
.scroll-btn > *.active {
 opacity: 0.8;
 filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.scroll-btn .mouse {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 35px;
 height: 55px;
 margin: 0 auto 20px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 3px solid white;
 border-radius: 23px;
}
.scroll-btn .mouse > * {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 29%;
 left: 50%;
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px;
 margin: -4px 0 0 -4px;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-animation: ani-mouse 2.5s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: ani-mouse 2.5s linear infinite;
 animation: ani-mouse 2.5s linear infinite;
```

```html
section class="grid-x align-middle section-two">
    <section class="small-12 medium-5 section-two-container">
      <div class="grid-x grid-container align-middle">
        <div class="small-12 hide-for-small-only squiggel"><img src="img/red-squiggel.png" style=" height: 350px;"></div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="small-12 medium-7 section-two-container">
      <div class="grid-x align-top grid-container ">
        <div class="small-4 medium-4 large-5 flex-child-auto"><h1 class="number"> 1 </h1></div>
        <div class="small-8 medium-8 large-7 flex-child-auto">
          <h2 class="sub-header-one">website design and development</h2>
          <p class="item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>

  <!-- End Section Two -->

  <section class="grid-x align-middle section-three">
        <div class="section-three-content small-12 medium-7">
          <div class="grid-x grid-container grid-padding-x align-center">
            <div class="small-4 medium-4 large-5 "><h1 class="number"> 2 </h1></div>
            <div class="small-8 medium-8 large-7 ">
              <h2 class="sub-header-one">search engine optimization</h2>
              <p class="item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-three-content grid-container small-12 medium-5 iphone"><img src="img/iphone-x.png"></div>
  </section>

  <section class="grid-x align-middle section-four">
  </section>
```

Comment: First of all, Welcome to StackOverFlow. The question you have asked is too broad and opinion based. Please consider asking a peer or one of your co-worker on this topic or you may check different websites. On stackoverflow, questions are mostly focused on problem solving in different aspect. For more information, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think this question is better suited for the Code Review Stack Exchange site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/